# Find by multiple columns and rows criteria sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

I have Paths and Criteria tables in PostgreSQL. Paths have multiple criteria that should be fulfilled to be selected.

Path table with (`id`, `name`), Criteria table with (`id`, `key`, `value`, `path_id`)

I need to create an SQL query for selecting a single path that fulfills two or more criteria inputs (for example, age of 30 and male gender). I have tried `ANY` as given below.

```
SELECT p.*, array_agg(c.*) as criteria 
FROM paths as p 
INNER JOIN criteria as c ON c.path_id = p.id 
WHERE (c.key, c.value) = ANY (array[
    ("age","30"),
    ("gender","male") 
    ])
GROUP BY p.id
```

But this gets a path whenever any one of the criteria is met (`whether age = 30 or sex = "male"` not both). I replaced `ANY` with `ALL` but that doesn't return any value at all.

Comment: You must add `HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 2`. Because your criteria array have 2 elements.

Comment: It might be easier to store the criteria information as a `jsonb` column in the `path` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed you correctly, you need to move the conditions to the `having` clause instead of the `where` clause. Also if you want the records that satisfy all conditions, then you need to check for each condition individually:

```
select p.*, array_agg(c.key || ':' || c.value) as criteria
from paths p
inner join criteria c on c.path_id = p.id
group by p.id
having
    count(*) filter(where c.key = 'age' and c.value = '30') > 0
    and count(*) filter(where c.key = 'gender' and c.value = 'male') > 0
```

This can also be expressed with two `EXISTS` conditions, which should be a quit efficient query with an index on `criteria(path_id, key, value)` (but then you loose the ability to aggregate all the criteria):

```
select p.*
from paths p
where
    exists (
        select 1 
        from criteria c
        where c.path_id = p.id and c.key = 'age' and c.value = '30'
    )
    and exists (
        select 1 
        from criteria c
        where c.path_id = p.id and c.key = 'gender' and c.value = 'male'
    )
```

Comment: Thank you! The first query works for me. I don't know how your answer compares to @a_horse_with_no_name 's in performance. I may need to check that.

Comment: I believe both approaches can also be used as the basis for filtering on a many-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with key/value pairs, it might be easier to aggregate the criterias into JSON objects and use Postgres' json functions to select those you want:

```
select p.*, c.*
from paths as p 
  join (
     select path_id, jsonb_object_agg(key, value) as all_criteria
     from criteria
     group by path_id
     having jsonb_object_agg(key, value) @> '{"age": "30", "gender": "male"}'
  )  c on c.path_id = p.id
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=63659eaff9bd1b0b4ee5ed19e114bc70)

Comment: This has the nice attribute that it ensures that *both* pairs are in the result -- even if there are multiple values for "age" or "gender".

Comment: @GordonLinoff: and it's easily changeable to find those that have **only** those key/value pairs by changing `@>` to `=`

Comment: The ability to specify all criteria in a single json is a plus for me. Thanks!